# Magento2: what is the difference between referenceContainer and referenceBlock

Tags: layout, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

Both `referenceBlock` and `referenceContainer` entities are used in layout in magento2.
What is the main difference between them and how can I relate these entities to magento1.*.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

basically containers are the equivalent of the `core/text_list` blocks in magento 1.
"philosophically" they work the same, the only difference is that `containers` are predefined blocks that only support other child blocks.
Some examples are `content`, `after.body.start`, `header-wrapper`.
You can see all defined containers for example in the `Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/*`.

Here is an example from `empty.xml`.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                    <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom" as="page_bottom" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

basically what's defined as `<container name="..." />` can be accessed by `referenceContainer`. what's declared as `<block .... />` can be referenced by `referenceBlock`

Comment: I want to add a custom static cms block under the price on PDP page, the alignment not properly set. Workout : code - https://justpaste.it/35xpq path (custom theme) - app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/grocery_gourmet/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml