# How can i include JS script to .html page in module / Or any other way to add script.js in module template?

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento 2 and i am integrating some **payment gateway** in JS.

I need to add  `script.js` in `default.html` which is at this path location.

> magento2\app\code\vendor\module_name\view\frontend\web\template\payment\default.html

Location of JS script file is at this path.

> magento2\app\code\vendor\module_name\js\script.js

Answer (score 2):

add your Js file

```
app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/script.js
```

script.js:

Then add Js File to Your layout File.

```
app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml
```

like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <head>
          <css src="css/mycss.css" />
          <script src="js/script.js"/>
     </head> 
       <body>
         <referenceContainer name="content">
              <block class="vendor\Module\Block\class" template="vendor_Module::class.phtml"/>
         </referenceContainer>  
     </body> 
    </page>
```

Comment: ` <referenceContainer name="content">` 

     Is this also necessary?

Comment: I just need to require the JS script on the checkout page so that I can use the method here " module_name/js/view/payment/test.js".

Comment: for referencecontainer and block use please read this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248735/magento-2-when-to-use-referencecontainer-and-when-referenceblock?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: <block class="vendor\Module\Block\class" template="vendor_Module::class.phtml"/> in this you should need to define your phtml class file

Comment: for adding js file at checkout please check this link it will help you.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215751/adding-js-to-the-checkout

Comment: Hi, where can i add this ' requirejs-config.js ' in the above given module and what should be the path to add script.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100519/discussion-between-garry-and-sangeeta-chandaliya).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the head code to `checkout_index_index.xml` solved my problem

> app\code\vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<head>
    <!-- Add local resources -->
    <script src="vendor_module::lib/dist/libscript.min.js"/>
</head>
```